# New Item Not Indexing?

Tags: sharepoint-online

I've got a very large list with a column that has been indexed, but when I add new items to the list, I cannot find them through the search feature.  Any idea why?

Comment: New items will only appear after Search Crawl captures it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharePoint Online is set to do a continuous crawl, and should take ~15 minutes for results to show in search results. However, in times of heavy use, that can increase to hours.

This link provides more information:

http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2013/10/waiting-for-search-crawl-in-office-365.html

If you want immediate results then probably you should look for hybrid solutions as explained in the above blog

Comment: Thank you!  This was correct.  It took a little over two hours, but added just fine. Thank you all for your help

Answer (score 1):

The items have to be crawled before search will pick them up.  You will have to check to see what your continuous and incremental crawls are set up for in your environment.  For me, new items will appear in search at about every half hour mark of the day.